# addToInventory won't add at least one item to the list

Tags: python, list, function, if-statement, inventory-management

```
inventario = {'Funi': 1, 'Pozioni': 2, 'Monete': 10, 'Arco': 1, 'Frecce': 3, 'Spada': 1, 'Smeraldi':0, 'Spada epica':0}

def display_inventory(inventario):
    total_items = 0
    print ("Inventario attuale: ")
    for oggetto in inventario:
        print(str(inventario[oggetto]) + ' ' + oggetto)
        total_items += inventario[oggetto]
    print("Numero totale di oggetti: " + str(total_items))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    display_inventory(inventario)

volte = int(input("Quante volte vuoi combattere? "))
cont = 0
vita = volte * 10
giocoON = True
monete = 10
poz = 2
funi = 1
spada2 = 0
smeraldi = 0

while giocoON == True:
    import random
    rnd = random.randint(1, 5)
    mostro = 10 + rnd
    frecce = 3
    print("•••• I tuoi punti vita sono " + str(vita) + "! ••••")
    print("•••• E' apparso un mostro di livello " + str(rnd) + "! ••••")
    while mostro > 0 and vita > 0 and giocoON == True:
        if cont >= volte:
            print(" ✓ Hai finito! ✓ ")
            giocoON = False
            break
        scelta = input ("""  Cosa vuoi fare?
        1. Attacca con spada (-5 vita)
        2. Attacca con arco e frecce (-7 vita / -1 freccia)
        3. Acquista nel negozio (Monete o smeraldi per oggetti)
        4. Utilizza pozione (-2 danno / + 5 vita)
        5. Utilizza fune (Salta battaglia attuale)
        6. Utilizza spada epica (-10 vita)
        """)
        if scelta == "1":
            print("•••• Hai attaccato il mostro con la spada, infliggendogli 5 di danno! ••••")
            mostro = mostro - 5
            dmg = random.randint(1, 5)
            vita = vita - dmg
            print("•••• Il mostro ti ha attaccato a sua volta togliendoti " + str(dmg) + "! ••••")
            print("•••• I tuoi punti vita sono " + str(vita) + "! ••••")
            print("•••• Il mostro ha " + str(mostro) + " punti vita! ••••")
        if scelta == "2":
            if frecce > 0:
                print("•••• Hai attaccato il mostro con l'arco, infliggendogli 7 di danno! ••••")
                mostro = mostro - 7
                dmg = random.randint(1, 5)
                vita = vita - dmg
                print("•••• Il mostro ti ha attaccato a sua volta togliendoti " + str(dmg) + "! ••••")
                print("•••• I tuoi punti vita sono " + str(vita) + "! ••••")
                print("•••• Il mostro ha " + str(mostro) + " punti vita! ••••")
                frecce = frecce - 1
                print("•••• Ora hai " + str(frecce) + " frecce! ••••")
            else:
                print("✗ Non hai frecce! ✗")
                print("•••• Il mostro non ha pietà e ti attacca comunque! ••••")
                dmg = random.randint(1, 5)
                vita = vita - dmg
                print("•••• I tuoi punti vita sono " + str(vita) + "! ••••")
        if scelta == "3":
            negozio = input ("""  Cosa vuoi fare?
            1. Acquista 5 frecce (-10 monete) [7 di danno ai mostri]
            2. Acquista 3 pozioni (-10 monete) [+ 5 vita e - 2 di danno]
            3. Acquista fune (-20 monete) [Salti una battaglia]
            4. Acquista spada epica (-3 smeraldi) [-10 vita]
            """)
            if negozio == "1":
                if monete >= 10:
                    print(" ✓ Acquisto effettuato! ✓ ")
                    frecce = frecce + 10
                    print("•••• Ora hai " + str(frecce) + " frecce! ••••")
                else:
                    print(" ✗ Non hai abbastanza monete! Puoi guadagnarle uccidendo mostri! ✗")
            if negozio == "2":
                if monete >= 10:
                    print(" ✓ Acquisto effettuato! ✓ ")
                    poz = poz + 3
                    print("•••• Ora hai " + str(poz) + " pozioni! ••••")
                else:
                    print(" ✗ Non hai abbastanza monete! Puoi guadagnarle uccidendo mostri! ✗")
            if negozio == "3":
                if monete >= 20:
                    print(" ✓ Acquisto effettuato! ✓ ")
                    funi = funi + 1
                    print("•••• Ora hai " + str(funi) + " funi! ••••")
                else:
                    print(" ✗ Non hai abbastanza monete! Puoi guadagnarle uccidendo mostri! ✗")
            if negozio == "4":
                if smeraldi >= 3 and spada2 == 0:
                    print(" ✓ Acquisto effettuato! ✓ ")
                    spada2 = spada2 + 1
                    print("•••• Ora hai la spada epica! ••••")
                else:
                    if spada2 != 0:
                        print(" ✗ Hai gia' la spada epica ✗ ")
                    else:
                        print(" ✗ Non hai abbastanza smeraldi! Puoi guadagnarli uccidendo mostri! ✗ ")
            if scelta != "1" and "2" and "3" and "4":
                print(" Numero inesistente nella lista, riprova ↺ ")
        if scelta == "4":
            if poz >= 1:
                print("•••• Hai utilizzato una pozione! ••••")
                vita = vita + 5
                dmg = random.randint(1, 5)
                vita = vita - dmg - 2
                print("•••• Il mostro ti ha attaccato, ma facendoti meno male, togliendoti " + str(dmg) + "! ••••")
                print("•••• I tuoi punti vita sono " + str(vita) + "! ••••")
                poz = poz - 1
                print("•••• Ora hai " + str(poz) + " pozioni! ••••")
            else:
                print(" ✗ Non hai pozioni! ✗")
        if scelta == "5":
            if funi >= 1:
                print("•••• Hai utilizzato una fune! ••••")
                funi = funi - 1
                print("•••• Ora hai " + str(funi) + " funi! ••••")
                cont = cont + 1
            else:
                print("✗ Non hai frecce! ✗")
                print("•••• Il mostro non ha pietà e ti attacca comunque! ••••")
                dmg = random.randint(1, 5)
                vita = vita - dmg
                print("•••• I tuoi punti vita sono " + str(vita) + "! ••••")
        if scelta == "6":
            if spada2 == 1:
                print("•••• Hai attaccato il mostro con la spada epica, infliggendogli 10 di danno! ••••")
                mostro = mostro - 10
                dmg = random.randint(1, 5)
                vita = vita - dmg
                print("•••• Il mostro ti ha attaccato a sua volta togliendoti " + str(dmg) + "! ••••")
                print("•••• I tuoi punti vita sono " + str(vita) + "! ••••")
                print("•••• Il mostro ha " + str(mostro) + " punti vita! ••••")
            else:
                print(" ✗ Non hai la spada epica, acquistala nel negozio! ✗ ")
        if scelta != "1" and "2" and "3" and "4" and "5" and "6":
            print(" Numero inesistente nella lista, riprova ↺ ")
        if vita <= 0:
            print("✗✗✗✗ Hai perso! ✗✗✗✗")
            giocoON = False
            break
        else:
            if mostro <= 0:
                premio = random.randint(1, 20)
                print("★★★★ Hai sconfitto il mostro ★★★★")
                print("$$$$ Congratulazioni! Hai vinto " + str(premio) + " monete! $$$$")
                monete = monete + premio
                print("•••• Ora hai " + str(monete) + " monete! ••••")
                fortuna = random.randint(1, 3)
                if fortuna == 2:
                    fr = random.randint(1, 3)
                    print("☘ Che fortuna! Il mostro ha lasciato cadere " + str(fr) + " frecce e tu le hai raccolte! ☘")
                    frecce = frecce + fr
                    print("•••• Ora hai " + str(frecce) + " frecce! ••••")
                mostro = 10 + rnd
                cont = cont + 1
                bonus = ['Smeraldi ★']
                inventory = {
                    'Funi': funi,
                    'Pozioni': poz,
                    'Monete': monete,
                    'Arco': 1,
                    'Frecce': frecce,
                    'Spada':1,
                    'Smeraldi ★':0,
                    'Spada epica ★': spada2
                    }
                print
                def add_to_inventory(inv, added_items):
                    added_itemsQ = {}
                    total_items = 0
                    for item in added_items:
                        added_itemsQ[item] = smeraldi + 1
                    for i in added_itemsQ:
                        if not i in inv:
                            inv[i] = added_itemsQ[i]
                        else:
                            inv[i] = inv[i] + added_itemsQ[i]
                    for i in inv:
                        print(str(inv[i]) + " " + str(i))
                        total_items += inv[i]
                    print ("Oggetti totali: " + (str(total_items)))
                add_to_inventory(inventory, bonus)
                if cont < volte:
                  print("➔➔➔➔ PROSSIMO AVVERSARIO ➔➔➔➔")
```

Ok so this is my code, i'll try to sum it up in the best way I can, as you can see it's in Italian, but i will translate it in english, this code is a game, specifically a turn-based game where you fight monsters and then when you win you get an emerald that permits you to buy a new sword, that was the full code, this down there

```
              ` bonus = ['Smeraldi ★']
                inventory = {
                    'Funi': funi,
                    'Pozioni': poz,
                    'Monete': monete,
                    'Arco': 1,
                    'Frecce': frecce,
                    'Spada':1,
                    'Smeraldi ★':0,
                    'Spada epica ★': spada2
                    }
                print
                def add_to_inventory(inv, added_items):
                    added_itemsQ = {}
                    total_items = 0
                    for item in added_items:
                        added_itemsQ[item] = smeraldi + 1
                    for i in added_itemsQ:
                        if not i in inv:
                            inv[i] = added_itemsQ[i]
                        else:
                            inv[i] = inv[i] + added_itemsQ[i]
                    for i in inv:
                        print(str(inv[i]) + " " + str(i))
                        total_items += inv[i]
                    print ("Oggetti totali: " + (str(total_items)))
                add_to_inventory(inventory, bonus)
```

`
is a part of the code that is supposed to give me an inventory item (Smeraldi), the problem is that it doesn't work as intended, the result is always 'Smeraldi : 1' it does not add the extra one, resulting in the user unable to buy the new sword at all.

Comment: ok i fixed the one with the "wrong number retry" thing, i simply wrote the wrong string lol, but i still didn't figure it out how to do the emerald thing

Comment: Please use a [mcve]. Just the part where the issue is